# What part of the Windows 10 SDK do I need to install to get uuidgen?

Tags: windows-10, sdk, uuid

I would like to install uuidgen, which I have [read](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/rpc/generating-the-uuid) comes with the Windows 10 SDK. When I go through the [installer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZjAFj.png), there are a lot of parts I can choose, and I don't want to install 2.9 GB of stuff I don't need. Which one(s) should I install to get uuidgen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Which one(s) should I install to get uuidgen?

You need to install `Windows SDK for Desktop C++ x86 Apps` which also automatically requires the following features

- Windows SDK Signing Tools for Desktop Apps
- Windows SDK for UWP Managed Apps
- Windows SDK for UWP C++ Apps.

[image]

[image]